# Java ZonedDateTime min/max offset

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I was just wondering what is the max offset in the java ZonedDateTime

When i do:

```
ZonedDatetime.parse("2017-03-13T00:00:00.0:+23:00")
```

i get a parse exception saying range can't be more than -18/+18

In that case how do we parse dates that have offsets that are more than 18 hours behind/ahead?

Comment: You don't, because such offsets don't exist.

Comment: See https://www.worldtimezone.com/ -12 to +12

Answer (score 1):

Such offsets don't exist. Just take a look at the list of UTC offsets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

As you can see the offsets reach from -12 to +14. There is no need for `ZonedDatetime.parse` to support other offsets.